# Cортировка по длине слова

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не пойму, почему код не работает. Может я неверно проверяю.

```
def get_min_len_word(string_list):
   return string_list.sort(key=len)

print(get_min_len_word(["bb", "aa", "fkha", "loinwnkf", "kaka, kfj"]))
```

На выходе список без изменений.

Comment: указанный в вопросе код, вообще не может список вывести (метод `list.sort()` ничего не возвращает, он изменяет список по месту). Вы должны увидеть `None` на экране с вашим кодом. Приведите действительный код, который вы используете как есть. Приведите именно тот вывод, который вы видите на экране (просто скопируйте). И явно укажите какой вывод вы вместо этого хотите -- чем текущий результат отличается от желаемого.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте `sorted` вместо `sort`:

```
def get_min_len_word(string_list):
   return sorted(string_list, key=len)
```

Разница в том, что `sort` сортирует исходный список, и ничего не возвращает. А `sorted` не изменяет исходный список, а возвращает его отсортированную копию.

На ваших данных:

```
>>> print(get_min_len_word(["bb", "aa", "fkha", "loinwnkf", "kaka, kfj"]))
['bb', 'aa', 'fkha', 'loinwnkf', 'kaka, kfj']
```

Видим, что ничего не поменялось. На самом деле все правильно, т.к. ваш исходный список и так отсортирован по возрастанию длины элементов (обратите внимание, что `"kaka, kfj"` - это один элемент списка с длиной 9).

Comment: Я пробовала оба и сортед и просто сорт.
Сортед ничего не меняет, а оставляет исходный список.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что `"kaka, kfj"` - это один элемент списка с длиной 9. Поэтому у вас исходный список правильно отсортирован по длине элементов.

Comment: Вот я лошара! Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort` только сортирует список, а возвращает `None`. 
Можно сделать так:

```
def get_min_len_word(string_list): 
    string_list.sort(key=len)
    return string_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Имя функции `get_min_len_word()` значит что-то другое чем ваша функция делает.

Может быть что ваша программа (после исправления) не удовлетворяет задаванию а вы хотели

```
def get_min_len_word(string_list):
    return sorted(string_list, key=len)[0]         # первый элемент упорядоченного списка
```